# Cosmetic issue when showing component descriptions with Install4J

Tags: install4j

I'm using Install4J 8.0.8 and I'm observing a cosmetic issue in the installer when showing component descriptions:
The second component is positioned too high and collides with the description of the first one:

[image: Installer with collision]

Is that a known issue or can I solve that problem myself (other than by limiting the description length for the first component)?

The offending install4j configuration file is available [here](https://github.com/Ginj-capture/Ginj/blob/4ece38a491bd7d478d211c77ea447a3531250896/build_installer.install4j).

The installer was built and run under Win10 64b with OpenJDK 14.

KR. Vicne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this bug and fix it for 8.0.9. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already fixed.

Comment: Thanks ! Will do. KR, Vicne